# Install hydra with openssl support

Tags: linux, ssl, hydra

When I try to install hydra from source with `./configure` I get the following message that comes up:

```
 Checking for openssl (libssl, libcrypto, ssl.h, sha.h) ...
                                                   ... NOT found, SSL support disabled
```

However, `which openssl` shows: `/usr/bin/openssl`

And `libssl.so` & `libcrypto.so` reside in: `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`

So, I'm using one of the configure options to force the prefix as it indicates I can:

```
 ./configure --help

 Options:
   --prefix=path              path to install hydra and its datafiles to
   --with-oracle=prefix       prefix for oracle include dir
   --with-oracle-lib=prefix   prefix for oracle lib dir
   --with-ssl=prefix          prefix for SSL headers
   --with-ssl-lib=prefix      prefix for SSL libraries
   --disable-xhydra           disable compilation of hydra GUI
   --nostrip                  do not per default strip binaries before install
   --debug                    show debug output to trace errors
   --help                     this here
```

So, I've tried variations of this, but still no luck with configuring with SSL support:

```
 ./configure --with-ssl-lib=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your makefile to specifically reference the brew installed version of openssl.

After running `./configure` edit your newly created Makefile and change the first line to look like:

```
CC=gcc -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

This should fix all those pesky ssl related errors the compiler is throwing at you.